# Connect or Express middleware to modify the response.body

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I would like to have a middleware function which modifies the response body.

This is for an express server.

Something like:

```
function modify(req, res, next){
  res.on('send', function(){
    res.body = res.body + "modified"
  });

  next();
}

express.use(modify);
```

I don't understand what event to listen for.  Any help or documentation would be appreciate.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You don't need to listen to any events. Just make it

```
function modify(req, res, next){
  res.body = res.body + "modified";

  next();
}
```

And `use` it after you `use` the router. This way after all your routes have executed you can modify the body

Comment: I am trying to use my middleware after the router, but it seems to be not triggered at all. It is only triggered if I use it before app.router. I am using it insite the app.configure block, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Make sure you are calling `next` in your routes, otherwise express won't execute any middleware after that route

Comment: what exactly means "after you `use` the router"? In a simple app with `app.get(someRoute, handler)`s and `app.listen(port, anotherHandler`, do I have to `app.use(modify)` after `app.listen`? For me both before and after it seems not to work (I added `app.use((req, res, next) => { console.log('after response'); next(); })` and don't see anything in console..

Comment: Not working for express 4, there is no such an property or method called `body` of `Response` object according to [api doc](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res)

Answer (score 21):

I believe the OP actually wants to modify the response stream once a middleware has handled the request. Look at the bundled [Compress](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/compress.html) middleware implementation for an example of how this is done. Connect monkey patches the `ServerResponse` prototype to emit the `header` event when `writeHead` is called, but before it is completed.

Answer (score 14):

[express-mung](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mung) is designed for this.  Instead of events its just more middleware.  Your example would look something like

```
const mung = require('express-mung')

module.exports = mung.json(body => body.modifiedBy = 'me');
```

Comment: Easy to use library!

Comment: but isn't this only applicable to json responses? What about text/html?

Answer (score 10):

Overwriting the response's [write](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback) method seemed to work for me with Express 4. This allows modifying the response's body even when it's a stream.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var write = res.write;
  res.write = function (chunk) {
    if (~res.getHeader('Content-Type').indexOf('text/html')) {
      chunk instanceof Buffer && (chunk = chunk.toString());
      chunk = chunk.replace(/(<\/body>)/, "<script>alert('hi')</script>\n\n$1");
      res.setHeader('Content-Length', chunk.length);
    }
    write.apply(this, arguments);
  };
  next();
});
```

Just make sure to register this middleware before any other middleware that may be modifying the response.

Comment: To simplify your answer a bit instead of `~res.getHeader('Content-Type').indexOf('text/html')` you may use `res.getHeader('Content-Type').indexOf('text/html') > -1`

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a module for doing just this called [`connect-static-transform`](https://github.com/KenPowers/connect-static-transform), check it out:

https://github.com/KenPowers/connect-static-transform

> A connect middleware which allows transformation of static files before serving them.

And it comes with examples, like [this one](https://github.com/KenPowers/connect-static-transform/blob/master/examples/standardExample.js).

Comment: Unfortunately the `transform` callback of this middleware does not receive the `req` and `res` arguments from the middleware chain.

Comment: I don't think this is an answer to the question, as it doesn't let you modify the response body. It's just for transforming *static files*.