# Node.JS - Get sent data at the end in a middleware

Tags: node.js, http, express, middleware

Is it possible in a middleware to get the data just sent by my API ?

For exemple I have a nodejs Server with this middleware:

```
    var middleware = function(req, res, next) {
       res.on('finish', function() {
          console.log(res.statusCode); // display 200
          console.log(res.body); // display empty data
      });
      next();
   };
```

And my API:

```
    app.get('/url', function(req, res) {
       res.status(200).json({name:'john'}).end();
    });
```

But in my middleware, I only can get the statusCode '200', but not the object `{name:'john'}`.

Anyone can help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `app.use(middleware);` after the router.

**Source :** [Connect or Express middleware to modify the response.body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896628/connect-or-express-middleware-to-modify-the-response-body)

**EDIT :** Sorry, the answer I link works for old versions of *Express*. I have read the *Express* source code, and **body** is never saved in **res** when `res.json()` or `res.send()` are called.

To edit the body in *Express 4*, you seem to need to override **res** methods, or use a package which do it, like *express-mung* (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mung).

Comment: I already did it, my middleware display the correct statusCode but not the body

Comment: Works fine ! Thank you very much :)