# Is there any Express middleware for response?

Tags: node.js, express

I am working in a Node.js RESTful API project with Express framework.
Every response of APIs has to include the "status" field in the response body, also in the header.
I think that I may have to use a middleware([Express Middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)) to achieve this goal, not containing the "status" by:

```js
res.send({status:200, ...})
```

From the documentation I understood that there is a middleware to pre-process the requests.
Even I found a question:[Connect or Express middleware to modify the response.body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896628/connect-or-express-middleware-to-modify-the-response-body) but it is to add a normal data.

But I am not sure if there is a middleware to add a specific field to the response body from catching the specific field in the field, the after processing the api requests.

I need your help.
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect or Express middleware to modify the response.body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896628/connect-or-express-middleware-to-modify-the-response-body)

Answer (score 0):

You can just write your own middleware to do it. Here's a simple inline middleware (not refactored to use modules):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(200);
  next();
});
```

The above sets the status code to 200 as default to all handlers.

However, I don't think you need to do this as express by default assume a 200 status response. If you find yourself needing to do this then you've got some middleware that's setting the status code to something else.