# Node.js Express.js: Getting the body of a sent response

Tags: node.js, express

A sample of my code will be:

```
middlewareA(req,res,next){
  res.send('some msg to client');
  next()
}
middlewareB(req,res,next){
  var sent_msg_body = res.<some method\property to get body>
  logger.info(sent_msg_body);     
}
```

I woukd like to retrieve the `msg` that was sent using `res.send(msg);`

Is there an option in `Express.js's res` object to do that after the response was already sent?

Comment: can you be  more specific in this question?

Comment: Why you want to get sent information from `res` object while you can get it during res.send() ?

Comment: it is a middleware, and I want to get the msg in the next middleware, that comes after the one that sent the msg.

Comment: Can you post your code here? so that is's more clear to resolve it.

Comment: It seems to depend on the version of Express you're using. This existing question's answers shows how to modify a response in middleware in multiple version (in multiple answers): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896628/connect-or-express-middleware-to-modify-the-response-body - the same logic should allow you to only fetch it.

Comment: ok so ive done it but i am having some weired behaviour. can you plz take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39611395/express-js-add-response-body

Answer (score 2):

You can use `request` object to get it

Do like this:

```
middlewareA(req,res,next){
  res.send('some msg to client');
  req.message='some msg to client';
  next();
}
middlewareB(req,res,next){
  var sent_msg_body = req.message
  logger.info(sent_msg_body);     
}
```