# Express.js- add response body

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to add a `body` property to Express.js' response object, which will be called every time the `send method is called`,
I do it by adding the following code as a middleware,

but for some reason, when I call `res.send` this function is called twice (once when body is object and in the 2nd time the same object butas a string )
1.why is it being called twice?
2.why and when is it being converted to string?

```
   applicationsRouter.use(function (req, res, next) {
        var send = res.send;
        res.send = function (body) {
            res.body = body
            send.call(this, body);
        };
        next();
    });
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are probably using something like this:

```
res.send({ foo : 'bar' });
```

In other words, you're passing an object to `res.send`.

This will do the following:

- call `res.send` with the object as argument
- `res.send` [checks the argument type](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3c54220a3495a7a2cdf580c3289ee37e835c0190/lib/response.js#L144)  and sees that it's an object, which it passed to `res.json`
- `res.json` converts the object to a JSON string, and calls `res.send` again, but this time with the JSON string as argument

Answer (score 6):

You have to use `res.json(body)`. It will send `body` as a response body. Make sure body should be object.