# How to create a Restify middleware that modifies the response.body?

Tags: middleware, restify

I need to build a restify middleware that operates on the body of the response that a handler produced. It seems that anything I pass to `server.use` is called *before* the handler.

I tried calling `next()` and then checking the `res` object, but was unsuccessful.

Also, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9897767/227332) might be what I seek, but I don't really need to `use` the router nor do I know how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a formatter.

I don't think using a middleware will work.  Restify ignores middleware once it finds a proper route handler (.get .put .post etc).  You could use a formatter instead. http://restify.com/#content-negotiation

When you make a restify server you can specify formatters.  These are invoked after a route handler calls res.send().  This will allow you to manipulate the body before sending it back.

```
var server = restify.createServer({
  formatters: {
    'application/foo': function formatFoo(req, res, body, cb) {
         // body is what was sent with the response, you can edit it here.
         // You finish processing by calling cb(null, body).  
         // Just be sure that you body is properly stringified.
         // See the restify docs above for more information.
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It's there a way to call the default formatter from within a custom one?

Comment: I don't think so.  The example formatter provided in the docs is the default formatter, so you could just append your custom logic to that one.